# MYSQL retrieve old values when updating row by INSERT/UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql

I need to update a table daily by its primary key, inserting new rows when needed, so the statement INSERT/UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY allows me to do it in a single query.

I'd also like to issue a text report listing the values that changed, but the only way I can think of involves 2 separate queries for each row: first a SELECT and then an UPDATE or INSERT.
(I could also SELECT and save the whole table in memory by a single query before starting with the updates, but the size of the table doesn't allow it)

Is there a way to SELECT and retrieve the old values, and UPDATE/INSERT in a single query?

Comment: In ODKU expression you may use column names on the right hand of `=` operator. In this case it refers to old value (Rather than `VALUE(column)` which refers to the value to be inserted).

Comment: @Akina that would help me use the old value as part of an expression to update a field. But how can I have the query return the old value to me?

Comment: INSERT cannot return something except the amount of effected rows or error code/message.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution but it's awfully hacky:

```
mysql> create table mytable (id int primary key, x int );

mysql> insert into mytable values (1, 42);

mysql> insert into mytable values (1, 47) 
    on duplicate key update x = case x when @old_x:=x then values(x) end;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+------+
| id | x    |
+----+------+
|  1 |   47 |
+----+------+

mysql> select @old_x;
+--------+
| @old_x |
+--------+
|     42 |
+--------+
```

This solution relies on a side-effect of using `:=` to set a user-defined variable. After the query is done, the user-defined variable retains its value during the current session.

Comment: "awfully hacky" is probably a synonymous of ingenious, but it is still 2 separate queries.  My ideal result would be to hit the mysql server once per row instead of twice. Maybe using IF EXISTS and if so a BLOCK with an UPDATE and a SELECT ?

Comment: @Henry INSERT/UPDATE statements don't have a result set. You can't return any data with those statements alone.